# ¿Como actualizar varios registros en Mysql desde PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

mi pregunta es como puedo actualizar varios registros de una tabla de Mysql desde php ?

En la variable   $conver2  se guardan los valores que quiero insertar

Puse el update dentro del foreach para que se repitiera la sentencia segun la cantidad de datos  que halla en $conver2 .

Si me actualiza los registros pero me  pone el ultimo valor del $conver2
Por ejemplo si en el $conver2  hubieran estos datos :

'6,500.00'// '8,100.00',//'11,100.00'.

Me estaria actualizando los registros pero poniendo en todos el ultimo valor osea  '11,100.00'.

```html
 <?php
$conexion = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'scabc');

$query    = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT valStockI FROM movimientos where idMovimiento >= " . $idMovimiento . " and idStockI= " . $idStockI . "");
            
$stockvalorplus = 0;
$stockvalorplus = $valornuevo - $valorantiguo;

foreach ($query as $dato) {
$a       = $dato['valStockI'];
$conver  = str_replace(",", "", $a);
$total   = $conver + $stockvalorplus;
$conver2 = number_format($total, 2, '.', ',');
echo $conver2;
echo '</br>';

mysqli_query($conexion, 'UPDATE movimientos set valStockI="  ' . $conver2 . ' "  where idMovimiento >=' . $idMovimiento . ' and idStockI= ' . $idStockI . ' ');

  }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu primer select query selecciona 3 records.  Tu update query es exactamente igual, entonces va a seleccionar los mismos 3 registros.  Puedes ser mas especifico al seleccionar asi:

```
<?php
$conexion = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'scabc');

$query    = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT valStockI FROM movimientos where idMovimiento >= " . $idMovimiento . " and idStockI= " . $idStockI . "");

$stockvalorplus = 0;
$stockvalorplus = $valornuevo - $valorantiguo;

foreach ($query as $dato) {
$a       = $dato['valStockI'];
$conver  = str_replace(",", "", $a);
$total   = $conver + $stockvalorplus;
$conver2 = number_format($total, 2, '.', ',');
echo $conver2;
echo '</br>';

mysqli_query($conexion, 'UPDATE movimientos set valStockI="  ' . $conver2 . ' "  where idMovimiento >=' . $idMovimiento . ' and idStockI= ' . $idStockI . ' and movimientos ="' . $dato['movimiento'] . '" ');

  }
?>
```